# How to find mapping between two hashes/dictionaries

Tags: ruby, dictionary, hashmap

I have two hashes/dictionaries.

The first hash represents price buckets and looks something like:

```
hash = {"499 & Under" => "0 TO 499", "500 - 999" => "500 TO 999", "1000 - 1499" => "1000 TO 1499", 
"1500 - 2499" => "1500 TO 2499", "2500 & Above" => "2500 TO *"}
```

The second hash corresponds to the number of items in a given bucket, but it only has a lower bound of the bucket as the key. It looks something like:

```
{0=>3605, 500=>3078, 1000=>1656, 1500=>743, 2000=>333}
```

The bucket size of the second hash is given to be 500. In addition I have information of the number of items that do not fit in any bucket of the second hash (>2500 in this case).

I want to create a mapping between these two hashes.

What I have done so far:

```
buckets = {"499 & Under" => "0 TO 499", "500 - 999" => "500 TO 999", "1000 - 1499" => "1000 TO 1499", "1500 - 2499" => "1500 TO 2499", "2500 & Above" => "2500 TO *"}
counts = {0=>3605, 500=>3078, 1000=>1656, 1500=>743, 2000=>333}
gap = 500      ##bucket size of counts hash
after = 681    ##num of items not in any bucket

x = counts
counts = Hash[x.map{|k,v| ["#{k.to_s} TO #{k+gap-1}",v]}]
##{"0 TO 499"=>3605, "500 TO 999"=>3078, "1000 TO 1499"=>1656, "1500 TO 1999"=>743, "2000 TO 2499"=>333}
counts["#{x.keys.max+gap} TO *"] = after
##{"0 TO 499"=>3605, "500 TO 999"=>3078, "1000 TO 1499"=>1656, "1500 TO 1999"=>743, "2000 TO 2499"=>333, "2500 TO *"=>681}
```

How can I merge the two elements from the count hash:

```
"1500 TO 1999"=>743, "2000 TO 2499"=>333
```

to get the count for the:

```
"1500 - 2499" => "1500 TO 2499"
```

price bucket?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I tagged it a python because logic is immaterial of language and similarity of hashes and dictionaries

Comment: If this is truly a language-independent question (i.e. conceptual, algorithmic) then ask on the [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange. If you want to know how to do this in a specific language, it fits here but should be tagged as such.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant way but this will work:

```
 hash = {"499 & Under" => "0 TO 499", "500 - 999" => "500 TO 999", "1000 - 1499" => "1000 TO 1499","1500 - 2499" => "1500 TO 2499", "2500 & Above" => "2500 TO *"}
 counts = {0=>3605, 500=>3078, 1000=>1656, 1500=>743, 2000=>333, 2500 => 4}
 value_ranges = value_ranges = Hash[hash.values.map do |v|
                  starting,stopping = v.split("TO").map(&:to_i)
                  [v,(starting..stopping)]
                end]
 #=> {"0 TO 499"=>0..499, "500 TO 999"=>500..999, "1000 TO 1499"=>1000..1499, "1500 TO 2499"=>1500..2499, "2500 TO *"=>2500..0}
 result_hash = Hash[counts.map do |k,v|
                   [value_ranges.collect{|words,range| words if range.include?(k)}.compact.pop || "2500 TO *",v]
               end]
 #=> {"0 TO 499"=>3605, "500 TO 999"=>3078, "1000 TO 1499"=>1656, "1500 TO 2499"=>333, "2500 TO *"=>4}
```

Like I said it lacks for elegance and readability but it produces results. Not sure where this data comes from but building the original `Hash` in this structure seems like it might be easier than merging the 2 afterwards.

Comment: `"1500 TO 2499"=>333` seems incorrect. it should be `"1500 TO 2499"=>1076(333+743)`